# Receive records matching array of primary keys in same order as they appear in array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have list/array of primary keys, now I need to execute SQL query to get records from a table in exactly the same order as they appear in the array. For example:

```
| id |     text      |
| 1  | random data 1 |
| 2  | random data 2 |
| 3  | random data 3 |
| 4  | random data 4 |
```

This query:

```
select * from sample where id in (2,4,1)
```

Should return rows:

```
| 2  | random data 2 |
| 4  | random data 4 |
| 1  | random data 1 |
```

What is the best way to do it in PostgreSQL 9.3?

Comment: BTW, Postgres 9.3 does not exist yet. Current version is 9.2

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
SELECT t.id, t.text
FROM (
   SELECT *, row_number() OVER () AS rn
   FROM  (
      SELECT unnest('{2,4,1}'::int[]) AS id
      ) x
   ) y
JOIN   tbl t USING (id)
ORDER  BY rn
```

The trick is to apply a row number with the [window function `row_number()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) which you can use to `ORDER BY` after the `JOIN`.
Find more ways (a more secure one among others), detailed explanation and links under this [closely related question on dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27279/how-do-i-preserve-the-order-of-the-original-elements-in-an-unnested-array).